# How to create JaCoCo xml report and xml summary for Microsoft Visual Studio Team?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, azure-devops, jacoco

I need to switch on JaCoCo coverage reports in Microsoft Visual Studio Team.

I can see the form:

[image]

So, I need the summary file. How can I create it?
Is it true that I need to create a report in xml format locally?

I am trying to create this reports, but I have a problem.
My project use Gradle, so I add this in `gradle.build`:

```
apply plugin: "jacoco"
```

And:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        testCoverageEnabled true
    }
}
```

But I can't see any reports from jacoco.
I can create a full jacoco report with Android studio, but it's the only html.

**How can I create the summary for Microsoft Visual Studio Team?**

Comment: Which build task you used? There is Code Coverage configuration in Gradle task, run test task with code coverage, then it will uploads the code coverage.

Comment: I use this configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46193721/how-to-create-xml-and-html-reports-for-jacoco-with-gradle The build is successful, but there are no reports

Answer (score 0):

For the Jacoco configuration, you can refer to the code sample here: [Gradle Example](https://github.com/codecov/example-gradle). I have tested it, it can generated XML report correctly.

And then you can run the build and publish the code coverage result from VSTS:
[image]

Published result in VSTS:
[image]